# How to route many documents to multiple folders in bulk using Content Organizer?

Tags: content-organizer

Content Organizer routes uploaded documents (per defined rules) ***one at a time***. 
I've uploaded a huge list of documents and want to route to 20 different folders in a document library.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1):

Serge Luca has already found a workaround for that: [schedule the Content Organizer Processing timer job or launch it manually](http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2010/07/10/the-sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-doesn%E2%80%99t-dispatch-bulk-uploaded-documents/).